# Is there a way to loop back to a previous line of code in Python v3?

Tags: python, loops

I'm new to Python, and I was wondering if there was a way to loop back to a previous line of code?

```
command = input('Choose [a]dd, [d]elete, [l]ist, [s]earch, [v]iew or [q]uit: ')

if command == 'a': #Add fruit command
    #Loop back to Command Line
if command == 'd': #Delete fruit command
    #Loop back to Command Line
#etc...
```

If I am doing anything else wrong, I would greatly appreciate further pointers.

As I am still new to this, if possible, I would like the answer to be as simple as possible.

Comment: No (and IMHO your question does not make sense and is unclear). Please take several weeks to read more about Python.

Comment: You could define input() as a function and call it wherever needed.

Comment: Function calls does what you want isn’t it?

Comment: Check if my answer makes sense to you! @ben

Answer (score 3):

When you say, `Loop back to Command Line`, I assume you mean call input again.
Well in python, we have something called a `function` in which you can define a piece of code, and that can be called when you need it.

So in your case, you want to `call` the command line again, which means taking an input.

Let's start by wrapping that statement in a `function`

```
def cmd():
    command = input('Choose [a]dd, [d]elete, [l]ist, [s]earch, [v]iew or [q]uit: ')
    return command
```

You can see that the `function` `cmd` takes the input from the user, and `returns` it, which means that whoever `calls` the function, will get the value back.

Now we can call the function by just doing `cmd()` as we do below

```
#Call cmd the first time and assign the value to variable command
command = cmd()
#Then we can use same function to call command again
if command == 'a': #Add fruit command
    command = cmd()
if command == 'd': #Delete fruit command
    command = cmd()
```

Some sample runs now will be

```
Choose [a]dd, [d]elete, [l]ist, [s]earch, [v]iew or [q]uit: a
Choose [a]dd, [d]elete, [l]ist, [s]earch, [v]iew or [q]uit: a
```

Or

```
Choose [a]dd, [d]elete, [l]ist, [s]earch, [v]iew or [q]uit: a
Choose [a]dd, [d]elete, [l]ist, [s]earch, [v]iew or [q]uit: d
Choose [a]dd, [d]elete, [l]ist, [s]earch, [v]iew or [q]uit: d
```

You can now build up your logic accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want is a loop. Take your input and process within a loop.

```
while True:
   command = input('Choose [a]dd, [d]elete, [l]ist, [s]earch, [v]iew or [q]uit: ')
   if command == 'a': 
      #Add fruit command
   elif command == 'd': 
      #Delete fruit command
   elif command == 'q':
      exit()
```

In the above example I used a while loop. If you want to learn more about loops visit https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-python/